# Finding time between two dates on two different rows from two different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Hi I hope you guys can help, I have a few tables joined to get the right list of information I need. now I am stuck on one last thing.
I need to find the hours from the end date/time in one row and one column and the start date/time from a different row in a different column.

```html
-------------------------------------------------
ID Name Startdate   EndDate
-------------------------------------------------
1 BILL 2017-10-10 09:00 2017-10-10 19:00
1 BILL 2017-10-11 09:00 2017-10-11 19:00
1 BILL 2017-10-15 09:00 2017-10-15 15:00
1 BILL 2017-10-22 09:00 2017-10-22 11:00
2 TOM 2017-10-10 09:00 2017-10-10 14:00
2 TOM 2017-10-12 09:00 2017-10-12 16:00
3 SAM 2017-10-13 09:00 2017-10-13 20:00
3 SAM 2017-10-14 09:00 2017-10-14 19:00
-------------------------------------------------

--------------------------------------------------------------------
ID Name Startdate   EndDate   Hours Diff
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1 BILL 2017-10-10 09:00 2017-10-10 19:00 NULL
1 BILL 2017-10-11 09:00 2017-10-11 19:00 14
1 BILL 2017-10-15 09:00 2017-10-15 15:00 86
1 BILL 2017-10-22 09:00 2017-10-22 11:00 162
2 TOM 2017-10-10 09:00 2017-10-10 14:00 NULL
2 TOM 2017-10-12 09:00 2017-10-12 16:00 43
3 SAM 2017-10-13 09:00 2017-10-13 20:00 NULL
3 SAM 2017-10-14 09:00 2017-10-14 19:00 13
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```js
SELECT 
a.ID
,b.FirstName
,b.LastName
,c.StartTime
,c.EndTime

from
table1 as a
inner join table2 as b on a.idnumber = b.idnumber
left join table3 as c on a.idnumber = c.idnumber

where

((Select Count(idnumber) as expr1
From table1 as ab
where idnumber = a.idnumber))<=1)

Order by a.idnumber
```

Having it done in SQL would be good but also if it's simpler to do in SSRS in an expression instead of SQL as this is being put into a report that would be awesome.

Any help would be awesome, I'm sure it's simple just having issues.
Thanks.

Comment: Use datediff() and keep interval as hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this simple case, you can use:

```
select id, name, startdate, enddate,
   DATEDIFF(hh, (
     select MAX(enddate) 
     from Table1 as T2
     where T1.id = T2.id
     and   T1.startdate > T2.enddate ), startdate)
   as [Hours Diff]
from table1 as T1
order by id, startdate
```

There is a working example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/95827/8

Answer (score 0):

Are the rows that you are wanting to compare in order? 
Row2 enddate vs Row1 startdate
Row3 enddate vs Row2 startdate
etc...

If this is the case you can use a "lag" function to bring in the values from a different row into the current row that is being compared.

I did something like this with Turophile's code:

```
select 
  id, 
  name, 
  startdate, 
  enddate,
datediff(hh,lag(startdate)over(partition by name order by startdate 
asc),enddate)

from 
  table1 as T1
order by id, startdate
```

Comment: Thank you, for some reason, the LAG is not working for me but this will help in the future. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `LAG()`-to get previous record data and `DATEDIFF`- to get the date/hour difference

```
SELECT  ID,Name ,Startdate,EndDate,
        DATEDIFF(HOUR,
                    LAG(EndDate) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Startdate),
                Startdate)  AS  Hours_Diff
FROM    TABLE1
ORDER BY ID,Startdate
```

Result :-

```
ID  Name    Startdate           EndDate             Hours_Diff

1   BILL    2017-10-10 09:00    2017-10-10 19:00    NULL
1   BILL    2017-10-11 09:00    2017-10-11 19:00    14
1   BILL    2017-10-15 09:00    2017-10-15 15:00    86
1   BILL    2017-10-22 09:00    2017-10-22 11:00    162
2   TOM     2017-10-10 09:00    2017-10-10 14:00    NULL
2   TOM     2017-10-12 09:00    2017-10-12 16:00    43
3   SAM     2017-10-13 09:00    2017-10-13 20:00    NULL
3   SAM     2017-10-14 09:00    2017-10-14 19:00    13
```